# How to allow access to EFS from SFTP using lambda as Identity Provider?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-efs, aws-transfer-family

I'm trying to build an SFTP server for an EFS that uses a lambda function to check username and password provided against a Secret in AWS.

I followed [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/enable-password-authentication-for-aws-transfer-for-sftp-using-aws-secrets-manager/) but changed it a bit, I'm not using an API Gateway, I use the lambda function directly as identity provider which fetches the following data from secret Manager :

```
"Role" : "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/my-transfer-role",
"PosixProfile": {
    "Uid": 1001,
    "Gid": 1001,
    "SecondaryGids": []
 },
 "HomeDirectory": "/"
```

so far I can only connect to the SFTP server, but can't read or write what's on the EFS `Message="Unable to list directory: permission denied for /"`

I created a role and a policy attached to Transfer with permissions on my EFS as explained in [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/requirements-roles.html)

Is there something I'm missing in this configuration please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out I was missing the file system id on HomeDirectory, so I changed it to : `homeDirectory=/fs-xxxxxxx`

and it worked, thanks to Sagar from AWS for his answer here https://repost.aws/questions/QUlDjDeMI7TD6C6pN0tdc4gw/how-to-allow-access-to-efs-from-sftp-using-lambda-as-identity-provider

Comment: Could you please snippet of your Lambda code and sample secret manager values? I am running into missing POSIX profile error even though below handled in the code.